# how to include tags in permalinks of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

while using custom structure in my wordpress url , when i am trying to include tags, it shows me , it is showing errors , but when i add category , it reflects in url.

i want that the tag gets included in custom url structure automatically , how can it be done using wordpress ... please help ...

when i am adding /%tag%/ to custom structure field in wordpress admin , the url shows not found message.

Comment: Tread carefully when placing tags in your URL. If you change a post's tags, rename tags, delete tags, and generally change your tag structure over time (as you usually do), you can break every pre-existing backlink pointing to the post. Of course, depending on your purpose for tagging, this might not be so applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do %tags% in wordpress, you will get error.

here is a excerpt from the codex.

```
%tag% 
Starting Permalinks with %tag% is strongly not recommended for performance reasons
```

read more here http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: did this help ?